# Can not set PATH permanently in order to launch MATLAB system wide

Tags: shell, path, matlab, runit, artix-linux

I have the following issue:

I recently installed MATLAB R2018a in my artix linux (runit). I can launch matlab from the location where the launcher is, i.e.,
`/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin`, but if I try to launch it from another location I can't. So I tried to append the mentioned directory to PATH with different methods:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
export PATH
```

If I check with `echo PATH`, it shows the directory, but after reboot the directory is not in `PATH` anymore.

As the above method failed, I edited `~/.bashrc`:

```
export MATLAB_HOME=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$MATLAB_HOME
```

then I sourced the file. If I check with `echo $PATH` it shows the directory, but after reboot the directory is not in `$PATH` anymore.

The last method failed too, so I edited `~/.config/shell/profile`

the same result as before.

Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong? I am new to artix runit so maybe I made a big mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please review the question and make sure there are no typos - I assume you mean `$PATH` in most places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the lines

```
MATLAB_HOME="/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin"
PATH="$MATLAB_HOME:$PATH"
```

into `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @PQCraft. I tried your suggested code in both ~/.profile and then in ~/.bashrc but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Arturo Hmm, try adding an echo line like `echo Running .bashrc` to the files to see if it is even running them

Comment: Yes it is running. I noticed that  the default shell is zsh, so i edited `~/.zprofile` but the issue still continues.

Comment: After you edit the appropriate dot-file, you will either need to logout/login again or "source" the file (ie. $ . ./.bashrc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

When i code:

`echo $SHELL`

i get

`/bin/zsh`


Finally i solved partially the issue with the help from artix forums. I created a script in 


`/etc/profile.d/ `


where i put

`export MATLAB_HOME=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2018a/bin

export PATH=$PATH:$MATLAB_HOME`

and now i can launch matlab from terminal, but not from dmenu, where matlab appears but does not launch from there. What could be the issue in the last case?
linux blackbirdsr71 is online now

Comment: Finally, i found that matlab has to be launched in dmenu writing the following

`matlab -desktop `

Answer (score 0):

I found from matlab forums that in dmenu i have to write

`matlab -desktop`

in order to launch it from there. So i think that this post can be considered as solved. Thanks to all for your kind help.